# How do I add the proceed to checkout button outside of the cart page using layout.xml?

Tags: magento

I believe this is the code within a phtml file that creates the "Proceed to Checkout" button:

```
<?php if(!$this->hasError()): ?>
    <ul class="checkout-types">
        <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('top_methods') as $method): ?>
            <?php if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method)): ?>
                <li><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However when I add it to another phtml file that is a sibling to cart.phtml I get an error saying that an invalid argument is being supplied to the foreach.

I then tried adding the block:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.top_methods" as="top_methods" translate="label">
    <label>Payment Methods Before Checkout Button</label>
    <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
</block>
```

taken from the checkout.xml layout file, to my own block, adfter tht totals block:

```
<block type="page/html" name="checkout_process" as="checkout_process" template="page/html/checkout_process.phtml">                  
    <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/cart/totals.phtml"/>
</block>
```

However this did nothing, am I missing something, I thought this would allow me to include the button?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you place that code? Not all blocks are printed automaticly but need to printed with `$this->getChildHtml('your_block')` (see [magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates)).
Here is a minimal example for adding this button to right column, I placed it in local.xml layout file:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="my.cart.button" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```